# How bad are these spots on my cucumber leaves?

Tags: plant-health, cucumbers

My cucumber plants have these brown spots on their leaves:

[image]

The rest of the plant seems unaffected: it's growing and climbing vigorously, and it's starting to form cucumbers. So is this just a cosmetic issue, or do these spots indicate a more serious problem that I need to address?